# how to set x-axis label as fixed in birt report

Tags: birt

am currently doing a report with chart so in that i had data which are in databases only showing ..but my condition is to fix label as constant then only if wt ever data in databases it will show according to label.....i had tried by to uncheck a iscategories its not  satisfied my condition ..

for example:

if am having data in database showing a month so in that am having data only for april,june,dec it only showing in categories axis 
but condition is to fix label as like jan,feb,mar,april,june,july,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec.....

is it possible by some script?

Answer (score 0):

Me too face the same problem but what i did is,i have select data for each and every month of the year so that if a value/data available for april,june,dec it will return the corresponding value/data otherwise it will return zero for unavailable month.

```
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -7 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -14 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -21 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -28 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -35 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -42 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -49 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -56 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -63 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -70 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -77 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -84 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
UNION
select 0,0,0,0,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -91 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Here i have select the query for last 3 months in weeks

Comment: how to select data for each and every month of year can u explain?

Comment: Use UNION operator for your query for each and every month.First select the  query for jan and put union and select the query for feb like wise for all months in the year calculate individual so that you will have your result-set for the BIRT CHART.